# How to save doc file at server by response.write

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, httpresponse

my problem is that this code download docx at client (Response.write..) but i want to download it at a specefic path(in server) how can i do it ?

```
    private void htmlToDoc(string html)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/msword";


        string strFileName = "docName" + ".doc";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + strFileName);

        StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();
        strHTMLContent.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head></head><body>");
        strHTMLContent.Append(html);
        strHTMLContent.Append("</body></html>");
        Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
        Response.End();
        Response.Flush();

     //   return strHTMLContent;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to specify which path the client downloads their documents to, for security reasons. The only thing you can do is prepare the document type and push it to the client to prompt a download, but the browser will then prompt the user on where to save it.

Comment: I must save the file on the server  because at the end I'm turning it into a zip file so I have to keep it on the server may there is another way?